# Formalizing the average of all non zero values of a vector

Tags: vectors

I am unsure about how to properly formalize the average of a vector, but only of those values that are not equal to zero.

Let s be a vector of size d. For instance:

$s = [5,0,3,4,0,0,0,0]$

In the previous example d = 8. I would like to mathematically formulate the average of all the values that are not equal to zero. In the previous example that would be as follows:

$\frac{5+3+4}{3} = 4$

I've come with the following formulation so far, which is the average of the vector, plain and simple

$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{d} s_{i}}{d}$

$\frac{5+0+3+4+0+0+0+0}{8}=1.5$

Thus, this is not what I intend

Could I please get some tips on how to procceed?

Comment: A notation that is in use for the number of non-zero entries of a vector is its "$0$ norm" (or "$L^0$ norm"), $\lVert v\rVert_0$. So you would write $$\frac1{\lVert v\rVert_0}\sum_{k=0}^d v_k$$

Comment: As an aside, be careful about what you plan to do with such an "average."  The averages that are more common in maths are common for a reason.  They have nice properties.  Your proposed average which ignores zeroes will not behave the same way.  For example, if you have two vectors $u=[10,1,1]$ and $v=[-1,-1,-1]$ we'd have $\bar{u}=4$ and $\bar{v}=-1$, and yet somehow $\overline{(u+v)}=9$, far from what we'd expect with other "averages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like $ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^d s_i}{\sum_{i=1}^d 1-\delta_{s_i,0}}$, where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta defined as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\delta_{i,j} = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
           1 \quad \text{ if } \ \ i=j \\
       0 \quad \text{ otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right. \ ,
\end{equation*}
in this way you add 1 at the denominator only for the non-zero elements of the vector (because  $s_i=0 \ \implies \delta_{s_i,0}=1 \ \implies \ 1-\delta_{s_i,0}=0$).

You have to define separately the mean of the zero vector ($mean(0):=0$) since it will give you a $0$ at the denominator with the above definition, or just define the mean only for non-zero vectors.